# Why doesn't $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq h_n $ proves that the limit is indeed $1$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am reading Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus, here:

> [image]

I believe what he done is the following:

$$\sqrt{n}=(b_n)^n=(1+ h_n)^n\geq 1+nh_n \\ \frac{ \sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{(b_n)^n}{n}=\frac{(1+ h_n)^n}{n}\geq \frac{1}{n}+h_n\\  \frac{ \sqrt{n}-1}{n}=\frac{(b_n)^n-1}{n}=\frac{(1+ h_n)^n-1}{n}\geq h_n$$

Now:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\geq \frac{ \sqrt{n}-1}{n}$$

And we have:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\frac{ \sqrt{n}-1}{n}=\frac{(b_n)^n-1}{n}=\frac{(1+ h_n)^n-1}{n}\geq h_n$$

And he concludes it here:

> $\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $[image]

But he adds another step after that, why is the previous conclusion not enough to prove the limit is $1$? After all, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, as $h_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ it should be $h_n\leq 0$, this should be enough, no? I've been thinking about what could go wrong, but until now I had no success. Perhaps $h_n$ could be negative? But for not well known reasons, it doesn't seems likely.

Comment: Well it is mentioned that $h_{n} $ is positive and by the inequality $h_{n} \to 0$ and then $b_{n} =1+h_{n}\to 1$ and then $a_{n} =b_{n} ^{2}\to 1$. Courant has instead used the inequality for $h_{n} $ to get an inequality for $a_{n} $ which is also fine.

Answer (score 4):

Showing $h_n \to 0$ is sufficient, but I presume that $b_n \to L$ implies $b_n^2 \to L^2$ has not been covered in the book yet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your approach takes more steps.

First you must remind the reader that since $b_n=1+h_n,$ from $h_n\leq\frac1{\sqrt n}$ we can conclude that $b_n \to 0.$
Then you must further prove (or at least use) the fact that $b_n\to 0$ implies $b_n^2\to 0.$

Courant collapses those two steps into one.